# How to set the content of a RichTextItem field in a Notes document?

Tags: java, lotus-notes

This one seems like it should be simple enough.  I'm writing a Notes Agent in Java; it calculates a fairly large amount of numeric data (a 6400-entry array of doubles) that I want to store in an existing document, updating a field.  Because of Notes' field limitations, I figured I needed to use a RichText field to do that.  (My initial attempt to write to a multi-value Number field resulted in it failing to save somewhere between an array of size 4000 and 5000.)  It's not clear to me how one stores that value in a RichTextItem, though.  All my attempts have failed.  In one case, using doc.replaceItemValue(), it seemed to convert the item to a Text List.  Getting the item, casting it to a RichTextItem, and calling setValues() or setValueString() doesn't seem to do anything.  This shouldn't be this hard!  Any pointers?

(Alternately: Any better suggestion for how to store my array in a document in the database?)

Thanks,
Reid

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to create a [RichTextItem](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NOTESRICHTEXTITEM_CLASS_JAVA.html) and use the methods on that object to populate it:

```
import lotus.domino.*;
import java.util.Vector;
public class JavaAgent extends AgentBase {
 public void NotesMain() {
   try {
     Session session = getSession();
     AgentContext agentContext = 
     session.getAgentContext();
     // (Your code goes here) 
     Database db = agentContext.getCurrentDatabase();
     Document doc = db.createDocument();
     Item subject = doc.replaceItemValue("Subject", 
     "Project description");
     RichTextItem body = doc.createRichTextItem("Body");
     body.appendText("Cartoon book for children 
      ages 9-12");
     // Print text of subject and body
     System.out.println(subject.getText());
     System.out.println(body.getText());

   // Save the document
     doc.save(true, true);
   } catch(Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
   }
 }
}
```

UPDATE:

If you need to edit an existing document, instead of creating a new rich text item, you would get the existing one.

```
RichTextItem body = doc.GetFirstItem("Body");  // instead of createRichTextItem
```

Comment: Thanks. The difference between what I'm trying to do and your code is that my document already exists and may have content in the Rich Text item.  In fact, the next thing I'm thinking of trying is removing the Rich Text field and re-adding a brand new one.

Comment: By the way, I still don't understand why RTI.appendText() works but RTI.setValueString() doesn't....  It all feels a bit flaky!

Comment: Rich text is a special type of item that contains an internal markup for formatting. So essentially you'll need to get the object and then modify it. There are lots of classes to help you, but it is not easy to manipulate and can get complicated quickly.

Answer (score 1):

You can bypass the Notes' field limitations. You can flag your item as «contains non-summary data» by using the [`NotesItem.IsSummary`](https://notes.helsinki.fi/help/help8_designer.nsf/b3266a3c17f9bb7085256b870069c0a9/e7855dea3d142d9a8525731b004a3092?OpenDocument) property. You need to set this property to `false`. But remember, you cannot use this item in views and folders.
Here is example:

```
Vector vector = new Vector();

for (int index = 0; index<6400;index++)
    vector.addElement(new Double(Math.random()*100));

Item item = document.replaceItemValue("YourFieldName", vector);
item.setSummary(false);

document.save(true,true);
```

Comment: I started to write that I tried doing this early on, and it converted my Rich Text to a Text List, which I figured I didn't want.  But if the setSummary(false) call removes the size limitation (64k?), maybe storing it in a Text List is fine? For that matter, would storing it in a multi-value Number item be fine if setSummary(false) works? That seems like the natural thing to want to do in this case.

Comment: you'll still have 64k limitation. It removes more vague total 32k limit on all "summary" fields in the document. But yes, you handle RT field as described by Ken, any replace/appendItemValue handles only plain fields

Comment: @ReidRivenburgh Is better to remove this field from `Form` design. If you do this, then this Java code will create a multi-value Number item. But as said by [Normunds Kalnberzins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25797134/how-to-set-the-content-of-a-richtextitem-field-in-a-notes-document/25801251#comment40386275_25801251) you still have 64k limitation. It's enough for 6400-entry array of doubles. But it can be not enough for 6400-entry array of string.

Answer (score 1):

As for the question of "better" solution. I've recently written some code where I serialize/deserialize Java objects as JSON strings. This way they are well readable and easily restorable. I guess for the plain array it's a little problem. Especially if you do not want to restore it and have not interest to look at it (well, but probably it should be one or other :-)

And yes, you have to store it in the rich text anyway. Alternative you might write a text document and attach it in the RT field (again RT :-). Pretty usual scenario and easy to do.

Finally you could store data as database objects, but I guess from Java you do not really have access to do it. And it does not seem to be in any way better.